# Xamarin iOS Back Button Stopped working after navigation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an issue where my UINavigationControllers back button has stopped working and renders incorrectly after navigating away from a view and then back to it.

To keep it as simple as possible, I'm loading a Split View in which the detail view is a custom UINavigationController. Nothing too special, it just sets the background color of the nav bar.

```
// shortcut for our navbar
public class SANavigationController : UINavigationController
{
    public SANavigationController (UIViewController root) : base(root)
    {
        this.NavigationBar.BackgroundColor = AppearanceManager.AccentColor;
    }
    public SANavigationController(IntPtr p) : base(p){}
}
```

From there views get pushed onto the navigation controllers stack, starting with a base view that is details about a specific customer on file at my company. This customer details view then supplies links to other views that drill down into greater detail different aspects about the customer.

There is a specific issue with one of the drill down views. When you first navigate to it everything works fine, i.e. the NavigationController's back button works and renders correctly.

[image: Working Back Button]

However; when I tap a button that pushes a 3rd view onto the stack and then navigate back to the second view the back button now looks like this and is unresponsive

[image: Unresponsive Back Button]

What makes this even weirder is that if I go to the third view a second time the back button will be hidden on that view, but it will still work if I tap where the button should show. Then if I navigate back to the second view the button has completely disappeared and is still unresponsive.

Any idea what might be causing this issue and how I can fix it?

Comment: Does this still happen if you remove the custom UINavigationController?

Comment: Yes the issue still occurs with a standard UINavigationController. Moreover there are other Views that get pushed and popped in the same manner that don't have this issue.

Comment: Strange indeed. Have you tried checking the NavigationStack on your ViewController as you drill down? The `ViewControllers` property on `UINavigationController` is what you're looking for. Does that have any discrepancies?

Comment: ViewControllers property has the correct views in it. One oddity I did find, it looks like the `NavigationController.NavigationBar.TopItem` property gets set incorrectly. On other views a `ToString()` on that property will show the current title of the back button and what looks like a memory address in hex. On this page (after navigating back from the third page) it shows the title of the current view I am on in that property. Not sure why this is.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question. It turns out this is kind of an issue the the `MonoTouch.Dialog.DialogViewController`. The view that was hiding the back button had inherited `DialogViewController` and was using the `(UITableViewStyle style, RootElement root)` constructor. In order for the `DialogViewController` to work correctly with the UINavigationViewController you need to call the constructor that includes the pushing bool `(UITableViewStyle style, RootElement root, bool pushing)`. So in my code this:

```
public class My2ndLevelController : DialogViewController
{
     public My2ndLevelController () : base(UITableViewStyle.Grouped, null){}
}
```

became this

```
public class My2ndLevelController : DialogViewController
{
     public My2ndLevelController () : base(UITableViewStyle.Grouped, null, true){}
}
```

Turns out google will only show the results that explain this if you include DialogViewController in your search term, which unfortunately for me was only after I figured out how to fix this issue.